# Issue getting SVG dimensions while preserving layout of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, css-grid

I've created a jsfiddle to demonstrate my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/8b26om5a/46/

I have three elements that share the same parent (`.parent`), and I want them to be in this order: `.my-div-1`, `.my-svg`, `my-div-2`. The two div elements have specified heights, and the SVG is supposed to occupy the remaining space within `.parent`.

I also want to get the height of `.my-svg` in order to render some other content inside of it. However,the height I get is not taking into account `my-div-2`'s height because that div has not been rendered yet. From the jsfiddle example, I'm printing the height of the SVG before and after rendering `.my-div-2`.

How can I accurately get the height of the SVG, accounting for the heights of the two div elements, while preserving the order of the three elements in `.parent`? I'd prefer not to compute in JS `my-svg`'s height by hard-coding the heights of the two div's (something like `const height = parentHeight - myDiv1Height - myDiv2Height`)

I know that I could wait for `.my-div-2` to render before I get the SVG's height and render whatever content I want inside of it. But in my specific application, I'd like to treat the SVG component as its own module in its own file. I don't want to break up the SVG code in two just to wait for the second div to be rendered. In other words, I don't want to do this:

```
// Render .my-svg

// Render .my-div-2

// Render children inside .my-svg
```

One solution I thought of is to fire an event when `.my-div-2` is done being attached to the DOM. Then, to handle that event, I can re-render the components, updating the dimensions of the SVG.

But I'm curious if anyone has other ideas. Also, I wrote the example in d3.js because that is what I'm using in my application. But this problem is not d3 specific.